# GmsClient "calling connect() while still connected" when suspended

Tags: android, google-play-services, chromecast

The `GoogleApiClient` logs the following error whenever the connection is suspended (i.e., whenever the `onConnectionSuspended()` callback is invoked):

`GmsClient  E  Calling connect() while still connected, missing disconnect().`

It appears that the client is automatically invoking `connect()` or `reconnect()` in response to the possibly transient error.  If the error doesn't resolve within 10 seconds or so, the `onConnectedFailed()` callback is invoked.

Is this error message just a false positive, or does it indicate an actual problem with my usage of the GMS APIs?  I'm using the Cast API, if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That message is not harmful. Are you seeing any side effects?

Comment: No serious side-effects; just wish I didn't have a faux-error cluttering the log.

Comment: @ali-naddaf, Once I got above error,if I try again to connect googleApiClient,no callback methods are called.Actually If it is already connected, how to get the connected googleApiClient object to pass my DriveApi.(or) how to disconnect existing one.I disconnected properly in my Activity onDestroy.

Comment: @Ramprasad you need to post a new question, yours doesn't seem to be the same as this post

Comment: @AliNaddaf I Posted my new Question here http://stackoverflow.com/q/27592181/884079.