# GoogleApiClient Calling connect() while still connected, missing disconnect()

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-drive-android-api

1) Calling `connect()` while still connected, missing `disconnect()`.This error occurs in following scenario,

1. Switch off Wifi and launch my App First time.
2. I try to connect GoogleAPiClient `onCreate()` of Activity
3. Got Error dialog, *Network Error:A data connection is required to connect to GoogleApiClient.*
4. So Switch ON WIFI, again open my App.
5. Got `connect()` while still connected, missing `disconnect()` error.

From my debugging I found,no GoogleApiClient connection callback methods are called when this occurs.

Note : This error not occurs, if I remove my google account from my device and add again. Also I used old version of Google play services.Is it affects anything.(As I used LocationClient API in my app I cant update to new Google play services, because it is updated to LocationServices API)

Comment: what do you mean you cannot update to a newer version of google play services because it updated the LocationServices API update your code

Comment: @tyczj I try to use LocationClient Api temporarily.So didn't update my GooglePlayService Library.

Comment: First, make sure your google play services are up to date. After updating that, try to first connect your wifi and then launch your app and see if everything works or not. Then if t does, look at your code to see what you are doing that is not right. There isn't much here from your side for anyone to really comment.

Answer (score 1):

Poblem solved, when all data from Google Play services app was deleted.
I think, problem is when play services remember every application which have succesfull authorization. But your application is not succesfully authorizated, or is authorizated in early version.