# calling connect(), while I am connected, DriveApi

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I have a problem, when I am trying connect to Drive api, I have got the following error log:

```
Calling connect() while still connected, missing disconnect() for com.google.android.gms.drive.ApiService.Start
```

A month ago it worked...
I tried check `if(mGoogleApiClient.isconnected())`, but same problem. Tried Api 16-21, google-play-services_lib from official source (up-to-date a month ago).
Does anyone know, where the problem is?

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    Log.d("activity","resume");
    super.onResume();
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    if(onResume == false)
    {
        onResume = true;
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            // Create the API client and bind it to an instance variable.
            // We use this instance as the callback for connection and connection
            // failures.
            // Since no account name is passed, the user is prompted to choose.
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Drive.API)
            .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
        }
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
    else
    {
        android.util.Log.d("archive", "msg");
        onResume = true;
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Archive.class);
        intent.putExtra("up", (int) 2);
        context.startActivity(intent);
        //Log.d("intent", intent.getExtras().getString("upload").toString());

    }
}
```

Comment: Possibly duplicate with this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27592181/googleapiclient-calling-connect-while-still-connected-missing-disconnect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Poblem solved, when all data from Google Play services app was deleted.
I think, problem is when play services remember every application which have succesfull authorization. But my application is not succesfully authorizated.